# How to compute the co-occurrence matrix in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing, feature-extraction, glcm

I have a question about the co-occurrence formula. How can I implement in Java the calculation of the GLCM of an image?

Concretely, I'm trying to figure out how to compute the number of times a pixel has intensity `x` and the pixel at its immediate right has intensity `y`. I also need to store the obtained value in the `x`-th row and `y`-th column of the resulting co-occurrence matrix.

The expected behavior is shown below:

[image: GLCM Alghoritm]

Here's what I got so far:

**CODE (NOT complete yet)**

```
public class MainClass {
final static int[][] matrix= {
        {2,4,1,3},
        {7,2,1,6},
        {1,1,2,2},
        {1,2,5,8}
};
static int i;
static int j;
static int x;
static int y;
static int c;
static int d;
static int maxValue = matrix[0][0];
static int minValue = matrix[0][0];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    for(i = 0; i< matrix.length; i++) {
        for(j=0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(matrix[i][j] + "");
            if(matrix[i][j] > maxValue) {
                maxValue=matrix[i][j];
            }
            else if(matrix[i][j] < minValue) {
                minValue=matrix[i][j];
            }                               
        }
        System.out.println();
    }       
    System.out.println("maxValue = "+ maxValue);

    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i< matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) {
             int x = i;
             int y = j;
             if(matrix[x][y] == 1 & matrix[x][y+1] ==1) {
                 count ++;
             }
             System.out.println(matrix[x][y+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT (ERROR)**

```
2413
7216
1122
1258
maxValue = 8
4
1
3
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
 at main.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:45)
```

I would prefer not to use third-party libraries such as OpenCV or jfeaturelib.

Comment: matrix[x][y+1] might be doing it in the loop at the bottom where you: for (int j=0; j<matrix[i].length; j++) { ...

Comment: yeah, but, when i try to erase that y+1 and try to make the Co-Ocurence its didnt work, so what should i do then?

Comment: I dont now what you are doing and your explaining is not good. So I'll give you one suggestion: avoid the periphery; if you have to go y+1 make j go j<matrix[i].length-1 - Otherwise good luck

Comment: agree with gpasch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code gets the job done:

```
public class MainClass {

    final static int[][] I = {
        {1, 1, 5, 6, 8},
        {2, 3, 5, 7, 1},
        {4, 5, 7, 1, 2},
        {8, 5, 1, 2, 5}
    };

    public static int getMaxValue(int[][] array) {
        int maxValue = array[0][0];
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                if (array[i][j] > maxValue) {
                    maxValue = array[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return maxValue;
    }

    static int maxValue = getMaxValue(I);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("I");
        for (int row = 0; row < I.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < I[row].length; col++) {
                System.out.print(I[row][col] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("maxValue = " + maxValue);

        int[][] GLCM = new int[maxValue + 1][maxValue + 1];

        for (int row = 0; row < I.length; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < I[row].length - 1; col++) {
                int x = I[row][col];
                int y = I[row][col + 1];
                GLCM[x][y]++;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("GLCM");
        for (int x = 1; x <= maxValue; x++) {
            for (int y = 1; y <= maxValue; y++) {
                System.out.print(GLCM[x][y] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
I
1 1 5 6 8 
2 3 5 7 1 
4 5 7 1 2 
8 5 1 2 5 
maxValue = 8
GLCM
1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 
1 0 0 0 0 1 2 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
```

**Notes**

1. I'm assuming that the minimum intensity is `1`. If you wish to consider pixels with an intensity value of `0` you should change the last two `for` loops like this:

   ```
   for (int x = 0; x <= maxValue; x++) {
       for (int y = 0; y <= maxValue; y++) {
   ```
2. The proposed solution yields the cooccurrence matrix corresponding to the displacement vector "one pixel to the right". If you wish to compute the GLCM using a different displacement vector you'll need to tweak the code. For example, the following snippet returns the GLCM corresponding to "one pixel offset upwards":

   ```
   for (int row = 1; row < I.length; row++) {
       for (int col = 0; col < I[row].length; col++) {
           int x = I[row][col];
           int y = I[row - 1][col];
           GLCM[x][y]++;
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks... this is what i wanted XD, so basically i got stuck with that 2 line of code int x = I[row][col];
                int y = I[row][col + 1];  
                GLCM[x][y]++;   thank you very much sir @Tonechas

Comment: can someone help how we can find glcm matrix for degree 45 and 135 . thanks

Comment: For 45 degrees you have to replace `int y = I[row - 1][col];` by `int y = I[row - 1][col + 1];` and change the columns limits accordingly: `for (int col = 0; col < I[row].length - 1; col++)`